# retrieve points based in Euclidean distance and axis values R

Tags: r, matrix, scatter-plot, euclidean-distance

I have a dataframe with 11 variables represented by letters a to k, plotted in a bidimentional scatterplot.

```
cor<-data.frame(X=c(0.36187115, -0.54755904, -0.82417308, -0.70806545, -0.77422866, -0.70003404, 
                  -0.70043884,  0.73602124,-0.89909694, -0.05937341,  0.93496883), 
            Y=c(-0.54354070,-0.81211142, -0.52775892,  0.40191296,  0.36820779,  0.28163131,
                  -0.26161395, -0.26386668,-0.31894766, -0.91541962, -0.04548996), 
            row.names = letters[1:11]);cor

a<-seq(0,2*pi, length=100)
plot(cos(a),sin(a), type="l", lty=2, xlab = "X", ylab = 'Y')
points(cor[cor$X<0 & cor$Y<0,-3], pch=20, col='blue')
points(cor[cor$X<0 & cor$Y>0,-3], pch=20, col='forestgreen')
points(cor[cor$X>0 & cor$Y<0,-3], pch=20, col='red')
abline(v = 0, h = 0)
text(cor, rownames(cor), pos = 3, cex = 0.8 )
```

Using euclidian distance I observe that the points (d,e,f and g,i) have distance less than 30.

```
d<-dist(cor, method = 'euclidean');d
```

I want to program a code R to identify all points with distance < 30 and retrieve one of these points based on the values of X and Y axis.

Ex: points i and g have a distance value of 0.206, based on the criterion of the axis point g must be excluded due the less value of X and Y axis.

However I dont have any idea to where begin.

Somebody can help me to begin the code?

Thank

Answer (score 1):

This function should work, although there's probably a better way to do it.

```
nearby <- function(data, d){
    dist <- as.matrix(dist(data))
    dist[upper.tri(dist, diag = TRUE)] <- NA
    pairs <- which(dist < d ,arr.ind = TRUE)
    for (i in 1:nrow(pairs)){
        for (j in 1:2){
            pairs[i,j] <- letters[as.numeric(pairs[i,j])]
        }
    }
    rownames(pairs) <- NULL
    colnames(pairs) <- NULL
    pairs[,2:1]
}
```

So to get pairs for which the distance between them is less than 0.3, do

```
> nearby(data = cor, d = 0.3)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "c"  "g" 
[2,] "c"  "i" 
[3,] "d"  "e" 
[4,] "d"  "f" 
[5,] "e"  "f" 
[6,] "g"  "i" 
[7,] "h"  "k"
```

Note that the function only works for points with two coordinates (points on a plane).

Comment: you could replace the loop with `cbind(rownames(d)[pairs[, 1]], colnames(d)[pairs[, 2]])`